# custom xml get error is not valid?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

i have default.xml in **frontend**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <head>
        <link src="Addon_Faq::css/faq.css"/>
        <link src="Addon_Faq::css/bootstrap.min.css"/>      
    </head>
</page>
```

when i load page notthing result.  In **system.log**  show:

```
[2015-10-23 10:33:37] main.INFO: Theme layout update file 'C:/localhost/magento_beta/app/code/Addon/Faq/view/frontend/layout/default.xml' is not valid.
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
```

everyone can help.

Answer (score 3):

This is late, and probably won't be marked - but in some of the xml files the

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Should say

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Such as in **/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layouts.xml**

I had this issue in creating a custom layout in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the following for css:
`<css src='Addon_Faq::css/faq.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`

and for Js:
`<link src='Addon_Faq::js/somejs.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>`

Comment: Thank @rob3000 I tried it. but unsuccess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried comment `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in default.xml is work!.

Comment: did this fix it?